# count a number of group of positive variables of equation $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k=n$ $\forall$ $x_i\leq m$, $1 \le i \le k$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Count the number of group of possitive variables of equation $x_1+x_2+...+x_k=n$ $\forall$ $1\le x_i\le m$, $1 \le i \le k$

For examples:

- $x_1+x_2+x_3=5$ $\forall$ $ x\le 2$ the answer is 3 because we have 3 groups $(1,2,2), (2,1,2), (2,2,1)$
- $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10$ $\forall$ $ x\le 4$ the answer is $4!+\frac{4!}{2!*2!}+\frac{4!}{3!}=34$ because we have permutation of groups $(1,2,3,4), (4,4,1,1), (3,3,3,1)$

I have no idea to solve the condition of the equation. I have tried to use opposite event for all variables like: $x \le 2$ change to $x \geq 3$ then set $y=x-3$ change equation to $y_1+y-2+...+y_k=n-3*k$ at both side of equation but it does not true

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what do you mean by $ x \leq k? $  You mean $x_i$ for all $i$ ?

Comment: yes, I mean $x_i \le m  \forall  1\le i \le k$. Let me redit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The coefficient of $y^{n}$ from

$$
\left(\sum_{j=1}^{m}{y^{j}}\right)^{k}
$$

Another approach will be inclusion - exclusion.

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-k}{m}\right\rfloor}{\binom{k}{j}\binom{n-1-jm}{k-1}\left(-1\right)^{j}}
$$

Basically calculating all positive integer solutions and then substracting the number of solutions which have any $x_{i}>m$

Comment: can you explain it more detail please? What does $y^i$ mean?

Comment: you have mentioned about "coefficient", does that mean the formula above is generating funciton?

Comment: @Becker yes You can say so. For Your first example, we want to find the coefficient of $x^{5}$ from $(x+x^{2})^{3}=x^{3}(1+x)^{3}$ which is $\binom{3}{2}=3$

Comment: Is there any other approach? I am finding information about it and try to understand because I haven't learnt about generating function

Comment: @Becker added the inclusion - exclusion, You may want to read about inclusion - exclusion from other source too

Comment: I think the second solution is more difficult than the first one =)). Anyway thanks for your help